# How do i get the node id using menu_hook

Tags: drupal-7

Hi I try to get the node id when user edit the node by the code below:

```
function test_plugin_menu(){
    $item = array();
    $item['node/%/edit'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'test_plugin',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' =>  MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    );
    return $item;
}

function test_plugin($node_id){
      dpm($node_id);
}
```

I get into a blank page when i edit a node. Please help, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The argument getting passed into `node/%/WHATEVER` is the node object itself.

The code should be:

```
function test_plugin($node){
   $nid = $node->nid;
   dpm($nid);
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you. Yes the function test_plugin() does get execute but i get blank page when access the node editing page. I think the problem is that i try to override the existing menu path that is already registered, because node/%/edit has been register in node.module

Comment: You can't use the route `node/%/edit` because it is already used by the node module. Just replace  `edit` at the end of the url. Then flush the cache.

Comment: Yes, that correct but what happend is I would like to obtain the the id and execute a function when user access the edit page of the node. Is there any best when to do this. I've been thinking of using hook_menu_alter to append the callback. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Thank you very much. I kinda found a solution by using the hook_node_load().